# Bootstrap Modal not working but modal-sm is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal-sm that I have made, but now I want to change it to a normal modal with a greater width.

When I remove the class 'modal-sm' and replace with just 'modal', the background goes darker still but the actual modal does not display.

If I manually go into the web inspector and unchecked the "display:none" on .modal i can see the correct modal pop up.

Any ideas why this isn't working like it should do?

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-gallery-<?= $shoots[1]['id'] ?>">Buy Gallery</a>


<!-- MODALS -->
<div class="modal fade modal-gallery-<?= $shoots[1]['id'] ?> in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body downloads">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2>test</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: class="modal-dialog modal modal-sm"> ?

Comment: You need to _remove_ `modal-sm`. Don't replace it with `modal`. That class is already applied to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.modal-sm` from the inner `div` - As in:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">regular modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">

<!-- remove modal-sm from here to get normal size -->
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Small size</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes)

Comment: OP wants a normal size modal. Not `modal-sm` - _"I have a bootstrap modal-sm that I have made, but now I want to change it to a normal modal with a greater width."_

Comment: got it, yes - I thought he wanted the other way around :( - thx, updated just before your comment :)

Comment: @Turnip thanks for the feedback, updated answer as well.